# How can I wrap a column of a pageview.builder around it's children in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello Friends Can anyone tell me how can I wrap this column around its children and also help me to understand why this `column` is taking the full height of the screen even though I am using `mainAxisSize.min` in `column`

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mini3/screens/welcome_screen/widgets/welcome_screen_slider.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text('Text'),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text('Sub Text'),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            })),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to wrap the `column` which is returned by `PageViewBuilder` around its children which are `text` and `sizedBox` in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: You can add whatever widget you want there & without any widget limitation. You could add 5 / 10 / 15 / 20 widgets inside the Column.

Here you go. I believe this is what you want. It is the minimum viable code. I hope it works. Feel free to provide acknowledgement in the comment below.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            // outer childrens here
            Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // inner childrens here
                      // Text("Widget 1"),
                      // inner childrens here
                      // Text("Widget 2"),
                      // inner childrens here
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            // outer childrens here
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use column because of multiple child, where you have used Container which contains pink color. Kindly let me know how can I use a column here which only takes the length of it's child instead of all available space

Comment: I updated the answer. Kindly check it out.

Comment: It worked, Thanks